# Is the "our" necessary in the following sentence?

Tags: determiners

Here is the sentence :

> This data is coherent with 'our' chemical intuition, because the exo
> form is less sterically hindered.

I really feel like some determiner would be needed, like **our** would be needed in that context. Am I wrong ?

Comment: our intuition about chemistry

Comment: Idiomatically *This data is **consistent with** [related data / principles / etc.]*, not "coherent with".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the "our" a literal reading of

> This data is coherent with chemical intuition, because the exo form is
> less sterically hindered.

is perhaps problematical. It's not clear who has the intuition. But if I saw the sentence written that way I would easily and unthinkingly infer that the intuition belonged to chemists.

(The pedant in me would want to see

> These data are coherent with chemical intuition, because the exo form is
> less sterically hindered.

but that's another question.)

Comment: I agree with your pedantic remark. But is it technically correct without the our ?

Comment: @Pastudent Most web authorities say "data" is a plural noun. But language is changing and the singular use is common. Check links in the search _is data singular or plural_ .

Comment: @Pastudent The **our** is required to make it clear whose analysis and conclusion it is. Without the **our**, the statement carries only the authority of the speaker, rather than that of the institution s/he represents.

Comment: intuition is human, not a quality of chemistry.

Comment: @Lambie Yes. So  when the explicit "our" is missing I supply it.